# p-inputSwitch (onChange) NOT working in Firefox

Tags: angular, primeng

the p-inputSwitch (onChange) of PrimeNg is not working in firefox, I got an error saying

```
ERROR ReferenceError: "event is not defined"
```

But the (onChange) works fine in other browsers.

Comment: It's working fine in firefox also. e.g. `<p-inputSwitch (onChange)="changed($event, checked1)" [(ngModel)]="checked1"></p-inputSwitch>`

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine in firefox(v62), IE(edge) and chrome.How you are using? Share your code. I am using Primeng v6, Angular v6.

```
<p-inputSwitch (onChange)="handleChange($event)"></p-inputSwitch>

export class SwitchExampleComponent{

   handleChange(e: any){
    console.log(e.checked);
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me as well:

`<p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="linha.ativo" onLabel="Sim" offLabel="Não" (onChange)="desativar(linha, $event)"></p-inputSwitch>`

Comment: I feel like most of the issues occurring due to primeng Version. Please try to update and check if this issue exists?